# using wakelock in 4.9 kernel driver

Tags: kernel, android

I'm trying to port a touchscreen driver that was written in 2014 for a device running Android Q (Hikey 960 on AOSP). The module won't compile because of:

```
#include <linux/wakelock.h>
```

which isn't there in the Linaro 4.9 kernel that the Hikey 960 board uses with AOSP.

Apparently, the functionality is there in `kernel/power/wakelock.c` and `kernel/power/power.h`, but I don't know how to compile that into my module. Or if I'm still even supposed to make use of wakelocks in driver modules like this? There must be a good reason the `wakelock.h` is not there any longer?

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution myself, posting for future reference: https://www.linaro.org/blog/converting-code-implementing-suspend-blockers/